# Can not insert German characters in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, text, encoding, utf-8

I am using UTF8 as encoding for my Postgres 8.4.11 database:

```
CREATE DATABASE test
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = mydata
       LC_COLLATE = 'de_DE.UTF-8'
       LC_CTYPE = 'de_DE.UTF-8'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

ALTER DATABASE test SET default_tablespace='mydata';
ALTER DATABASE test SET temp_tablespaces=mydata;
```

And the output of `\l`

```
 test | postgres  | UTF8     | de_DE.UTF-8 | de_DE.UTF-8 |
```

When I try to insert a German character:

```
create table x(a text);

insert into x values('ä,ß,ö');
```

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe42cdf
> HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".
> ```

I am using puTTY to connect. Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key element is the `client_encoding` - the encoding the server expects from your client. It has to match what is actually sent. What do you get for `show client_encoding`? Is it `UNICODE`?

Read more in the chapter [Automatic Character Set Conversion Between Server and Client](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html#id-1.6.11.5.7) of the manual.

If you are using **psql** as client, you can set `client_encoding` with `\encoding`. Check the encoding your local system users (on Linux type `locale` in the shell) and set a matching `client_encoding` in psql. You can avoid such complications if you use the same locale on your system as you use as `encoding` for your PostgreSQL server.

If you use **puTTY** (on Windows), make sure to set its "Translation" accordingly. Have a look at *Settings: Window - Translation*. Must match `client_encoding`. You can right-click in a running session and chose *Change Settings*. You can also save these settings with your saved sessions.

Comment: `test=# show client_encoding;

 client_encoding
-----------------

 UTF8
(1 row)`

Comment: 'UTF8' should be good, `UNICODE` is just an alias here. Now you have to make sure `UTF8` matches your client. I suspect you'll have to adjust to another encoding.

Comment: @baboso: "0xe42cdf" -- this looks like you are entering characters through putty using latin1 encoding. Either set your Linux environment to "de_DE.ISO-8859-1" or configure PuTTY to send UTF-8 characters.

Comment: running `"C:\Program Files\PSQL\bin\psql.exe" \encoding UTF8` is asking for password for user `UTF8` ...
how to change the client encoding when the system does not have postgreqsl installed? but is accesing remote database

Comment: @PresleyDias: Look for `encoding` in [this manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html), especially for the chapter "Notes for Windows Users".

Comment: Using `\encoding UTF8` or `SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8'` did correct output from `psql`, but I still couldn't insert German characters. I finally had to set the `LANG` shell variable to `de_DE.UTF-8` before starting `psql`, which did the trick (I normally use `LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8` locale because I prefer english dialogues, but had to change `LANG` to force `psql` to accept german umlauts). So I start `psql` this way:
`LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 psql database_name`