# How to declare a SQL INSERT Statement with a Unicode letter

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a sql statemwent, which contain a unicode specific sign. The unicode sign is ę in the polish word Przesunięcie. Please look at the following SQL INSERT Statement:

```
INSERT INTO res_bundle_props (res_bundle_id, value, name) 
VALUES(2, 'Przesunięcie przystanku', 'category.test');
```

I work with the Postgres Database. In which way can i insert the polish word with the unicode letter?

Comment: What is the template you are using for this table? Does it support the character set?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429655/can-not-insert-german-characters-in-postgres

Comment: should work just fine. Are you sure the statement parameters are *received* correctly (from wherever you get them)?

Comment: See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8091a/1

Answer (score 0):

Find what are the server and client encodings:

```
show server_encoding;
 server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8

show client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
```

Then set the client to the same encoding as the server:

```
set client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET
```

Comment: That's overly simplistic and often incorrect. Consider the case where the server is using utf-8 but the client is `psql` in an `iso-8859-8` encoded terminal. `ש` is a perfectly legal character in that terminal, and is encoded as `0xf9`. If you lie to Pg and say you're sending UTF-8 when you're really sending iso-8859-8, Pg will try to decode the client's `\xf9` as utf-8 and fail with an error complaining about bad Unicode input. It's rare that you need to change `client_encoding` directly; more often you just have to make sure it matches your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

No special syntax is required so long as:

- Your `server_encoding` includes those characters (if it's `utf-8` it does);
- Your `client_encoding` includes those characters;
- Your `client_encoding` correctly matches the encoding of the bytes you're actually sending

The latter is the one that often trips people up. They think they can just change `client_encoding` with a `SET client_encoding` statement and it'll do some kind of magical conversion. That is not the case. `client_encoding` tells PostgreSQL "this is the encoding of the data you will receive from the client, and the encoding that the client expects to receive from you".

Setting `client_encoding` to `utf-8` doesn't make the client actually send UTF-8. That depends on the client. Nor do you *have* to send utf-8; that string can also be represented in `iso-8859-2`, `iso-8859-4` and `iso-8859-10` among other encodings.

What's crucial is that you tell the server the encoding of the data you're sending. As it happens that string is the same in all three of the encodings mentioned, with the `ę` encoded as `0xae`... but in utf-8 that'd be the two bytes `0xc4 0x99`. If you send utf-8 to the server and tell it that it's `iso-8859-2` the server can't tell you're wrong and will interpret it as `Ä` in iso-8859-2.

So... really, it depends on things like the system's default encoding, the encoding of any files/streams you're reading data from, etc. You have two options:

- Set `client_encoding` appropriately for the data you're working with and the default display locale of the system. This is easiest for simple cases, but harder when dealing with multiple different encodings in input or output.
- Set `client_encoding` to utf-8 (or the same as `server_encoding`) and make sure that you always convert all input data into the encoding you set `client_encoding` to before sending it. You must also convert all data you receive from Pg back.