# Replace characters with multi-character strings

Tags: postgresql, encoding, replace, diacritics

I am trying to replace German and Dutch umlauts such as `ä`, `ü`, or `ß`. They should be written like `ae` instead of `ä`. So I can't simply translate one char with another.

Is there a more elegant way to do that? Actually it looks like that (not completed yet):

```
SELECT addr, REPLACE (REPLACE(addr, 'Ã¼','ue'),'ß','ss') FROM search;
```

On my way trying different commands I got another problem:

When I searched for `Ü` I got this:

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xdc27

Tried it with `U&'\0220'`, it didn't replace anything. Only by using `Ã¼` (for lowercase `ü`) it was replaced correctly. Has to do something with unicode, but how to solve this issue?

Kind regards from Germany. :)

Comment: Unicode escape sequences are in hexadecimal; you want `U&'\00DC'`

Answer (score 3):

Your server encoding seems to be UTF8.
I suspect your **`client_encoding`** does not match, which might give you a wrong impression of what you are dealing with. Check with:

```
SHOW client_encoding;   -- in your actual session
```

And read this related answers:
[Can not insert German characters in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429655/can-not-insert-german-characters-in-postgres/11430961#11430961)
[Replace unicode characters in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190078/replace-unicode-characters-in-postgresql/15190404#15190404)

The rest of the tool chain has to be in sync, too. When using puTTY, for instance, one has to make sure, the terminal agrees with the rest: `Change settings... Window -> Translation -> Remote character set` = `UTF-8`.

As for your first question, you already have the best solution. A couple of umlauts are best replaced with a string of `replace()` statements.

As you seem to know already as well, single character replacements are more efficient with (a single) [`translate()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) statement.

Related:

- [Replace unicode characters in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190078/replace-unicode-characters-in-postgresql/15190404#15190404)
- [Regex remove all occurrences of multiple characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953099/regex-remove-all-occurrences-of-multiple-characters-in-a-string/14953266#14953266)

Comment: I'm not so sure about the client/server encoding mismatch. In my experience, those kinds of mapping failures usually give "character has no equivalent" errors. "Invalid byte sequence" sounds more like the `client_encoding` is set to UTF8, but the client program is still sending ANSI data.

Comment: @NickBarnes: Well, the client sends data encoded according to the `clent_encoding`. `client_encoding` goes both ways. So we are probably talking about the same thing here.

Comment: Not quite. The server interprets the client's data according to the `client_encoding`, but the client can send whatever it wants. For example, if I fire up `psql` in Windows, it defaults to WIN1252. If I run `SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8'` and `SELECT 'Ü'`, I get an "invalid byte sequence" error. `psql` has no idea that anything has changed; it's still sending its data as ANSI.

Comment: @NickBarnes: Good point. My description in the previous comment was not quite correct. When using puTTY, for instance, one has to make sure, the terminal agrees with the rest ... `Change settings... Window -> Translation -> Remote character set: UTF-8`

Comment: @Erwin: That's the point. i am using SuperPutty and had to change character set to UTF-8. Though the problem should be solved - but: Select an address with an umlaut inside the street, the umlaut still isn't displayed correctly. Instead I am getting `Ã` instead of `ß`. However, my problem is solved. Thank y'all!

Comment: @Stefan: Once you have entered incorrect data in your tables, then it's there for good until you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Beside other reasons I decided to write the replacement in python. Like Erwin wrote before, it seems there is no better solution as combining `replace`- commands.

In general pretty simple, even no encoding had to benn used. My "final" solution now looks like this:

```
ger_UE="Ü"
ger_AE="Ä"
ger_OE="Ö"
ger_SS="ß"

dk_AA="Å"
dk_OE="Ø"
dk_AE="Æ"

cur.execute("""Select addr, REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE( REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE(addr, '%s','UE'),'%s','OE'),'%s','AE'),'%s','SS'),'%s','AA'),'%s','OE'),'%s','AE')
  from search WHERE x = '1';"""%(ger_UE,ger_OE,ger_AE,ger_SS,dk_AA,dk_OE,dk_AE))
```

I am now looking forward to the speed when it hits the large table. If anyone would like to make some annotations, they are very welcome.