# Unreadable (???) Postgres exception messages in Symfony 2 based project

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm getting unreadable exception messages where almost all characters are replaced with question marks (?) in application based on Symfony 2.0.18 and Doctrine 2.1.7

Here is an example:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] ?????: ? pg_hba.conf ??? ??????, ??????????? ??????????? ??? ?????????? ? ?????????? "123.12.12.123" ??? ???????????? "username", ???? ?????? "dbname", SSL ????.

I'm not worried about why I'm getting this exception. I just want to know how to make it readable.

Here is my doctrine config:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection:   default
    connections:
      default:
        charset:  UTF8
        driver:   %emp_database_driver%
        host:     %emp_database_host%
        dbname:   %emp_database_name%
        port:     %emp_database_port%
        user:     %emp_database_user%
        password: %emp_database_password%
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    entity_managers:
      default:
        connection: default
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
          StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle: false
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should change console encoding. 
But let me translate your message

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "123.12.12.123", 
user "username", database "dbname", SSL OFF
```

So fix your `pg_hba.conf` configuration file.

Comment: Can you tell what exact changes I should apply to `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: Add line like `host dbname username 123.12.12.123 trust` and read postgresql manual about this file to be sure your security is well configured

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a combination of `client_encoding` (defines what the server sends back) plus actual encoding settings of your client. Both should match your actual encoding on the client machine.

More Details:

- [Replace characters with multi-character strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676779/replace-characters-with-multi-character-strings/24677585#24677585)
- [Can not insert German characters in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429655/can-not-insert-german-characters-in-postgres/11430961#11430961)